# Azure copy file over ssh fail

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

Im trying a projetct with CI / CD, im working with azure devops and azure portal

I have 2 vnet

vnet A with my target VM

vnet B with my VMSS agent

in my ci - cd i have this :

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: "DL Artifact"
      inputs:
        buildType: "specific"
        project: "test"
        pipeline: "CI-test
        artifactName: "build"
        downloadPath: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"
    - task: SSH@0
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: 'POCTARGET'
        runOptions: 'inline'
        inline: |
          ls
        readyTimeout: '20000'        
    - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: 'POCTARGET'
        sourceFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/build/'
        contents: '**'
        targetFolder: '~/back'
        readyTimeout: '20000'
    - task: SSH@0
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: 'POCTARGET'
        runOptions: 'inline'
        inline: |
          ls
        readyTimeout: '20000'
```

My task SSH@0 work (it does a ls on my server)

But my task CopyFilesOverSSH@0 fail with the error :

Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: All configured authentication methods failed

I checked my networksecuritygroup and the used port (22)

Could you help me ?

Thanks

I checked my networksecuritygroup and the used port (22)

Comment: What was the VM image based on which you created target VM? According to your description, I generated test resources, where my pipeline running on VMSS agent from VNET B **succeeded** in copying build artifacts files to my targe VM in VNET A over SSH. My VM was created with the marketplace image `ubuntu22.04`. I suspected the old version of OpenSSH on the target VM might incur this issue. If possible, would you test with a new SSH service connection to access a new `ubuntu22.04` remote VM?

Comment: @AlvinZhao it's a custom image linux image made with packer
"os_type": "Linux",
      "image_publisher": "canonical",
      "image_offer": "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy",
      "image_sku": "22_04-lts",

Comment: Would you like to give a try to connect an Azure VM with the default marketplace image? It can help us narrow down the issue and to know whether the task failed in connecting specific remote machine or not.

Comment: @AlvinZhao i tried with Image offer
0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy
Image plan
22_04-lts-gen2 but the error is still the same, i dont know if it can come from my nsg config

Comment: I just tried to connect to my agent and try to scp a file and it work :/

Comment: Hi there, Have you tested with MS-hosted agent to run the `CopyFilesOverSSH@0` task? If the SSH service connection was created with the public IP of the VM in VNET A, the task running on a hosted agent should also work. By the way, could you please share the screenshots of your VM network rules? Please **don't** share sensitive information like IPs/user/password/token/certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Since Target VM and Agent VM is part of different VNet there should be communication channel enabled between them so that the traffic flows.

The best solution here is to create the agent in the same VNet where the target VM resides